# Possible to define a MooTools Class as a Browserify Module?

Tags: javascript, mootools, browserify

I'm trying to combine browserify and mootools if possible. I load mootools in the head of my page and then I attempt to define a class in a way that Browserify can parse this way in a file called `parallax.js`:

```
module.exports = new Class({

    Implements: [Options, Events],

    options: {
        container: window
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        console.log('test');
    }

});
```

Then in another file called `app.js' that is the main js file for the app, I require parallax.js like so:

```
var parallax = require('./parallax.js');
parallax.initialize();
```

But the call to initalize gives an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I suspect I've thought of this all wrong, but I'm unsure how to leverage MooTools alongside the modularity the Browserify permits. Perhaps MooTools and Browserify just don't play well together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work in a similar environment, only that instead of browserify I use [wrapup](https://github.com/mootools/wrapup) which is pretty similar,
your code doesn't work because you forgot to use the `new` keyword.

instead of doing

```
var parallax = require('./parallax.js'); 
parallax.initialize();
```

you should be doing

```
var Parallax = require('./parallax'),
parallax = new Parallax()
```

while MooTools exports on the global object so you should be able to require it, I usually just include MooTools in the page before calling my main cjs file.